# how to display a image by fileupload using jquery or javascript and path will store on db?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server-2008

in web page ,image control and file upload are there.if click file upload and select image file from local disc and it will display that image in asp.net image control without clicking another buttons or refreshing the page and before going to display that image its path has to be stored in database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this function, remember to include jQuery library. The following function uses a reader, to read data and set it to the image src. Image src can also be urldata.

```
 function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {//Check if input has files.
            var reader = new FileReader();//Initialize FileReader.

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#PreviewImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
            };
     reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

Add this to your image upload `onchange="readURL(this);"`. ASP.NET UploadControl has some problem with this function, use HTML upload control instead.

```
<img id="PreviewImage" src="" alt="?" style="width:100px; height:100px;"  />
     <input type="file" ID="ImageFileUpload" onchange="readURL(this);" />
```

Here is an working example http://jsbin.com/amoxip/2/edit#javascript,html

Comment: sorry can u please elaborate your coding friend..its easy to understand..y need this path because store that path for retrieving purpose.so please help me friend

Comment: You don't get path , you get file data and save it as an image.